# HREF generated in ERB with link_to is not clickable

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm generating a hypertext link to an individual article via ERB with the `link_to` helper method, yet when the link is displayed in the view it renders as an HREF clickable link, but it's not clickable (arrow doesn't even turn to a pointer)

I've tried manipulating the link_to helper and specifically the `article_path(:id)`, but the href path in the dev tools is rendering the correct path with the code below.

I've also double checked my routes, as well as permitted params.

```rb
<% @articles.reverse.each do |article| %>
  <div class="article_card">
    <div>
       <%= markdown(article.text[0..405]<<"...") %>
    </div>                        
  </div>
  # This is the link that isn't clickable
  <%= link_to 'Show full article', article_path(article) %>  
<% end%>
```

and this is what it renders in dev tools:

```html
<a href="/articles/20">Show full article</a>
```

I expect the rendered **href** to be clickable and GET the articles/:id

Comment: You might have some css that's doing that. Inspect your link and see if there's something like `cursor: default` or `pointer-events: none`...

Comment: @fanta I just double-checked all my stylesheets; no cursor or pointer-events anywhere

Comment: inspect the element using the browser's dev tools, maybe you have some invisible element above the A tag, maybe you have some javascript messing things up, the generated html looks fine, I don't think it's a rails issue

Comment: Thanks @arieljuod ! I inspected the parent elements and there was a z-index of -2 on an ancestor. Guess that's a big whoopsies on my part.

Comment: Please add and answer yourself and mark it accepted or close the question.

Comment: Was hoping @arieljuod would move their response to an answer so I could reward them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inspect the element using the browser's dev tools, maybe you have some invisible element above the A tag, maybe you have some javascript messing things up, the generated html looks fine, I don't think it's a rails issue

EDIT: check J.R. Bob Dodds answer below

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to @arieljuod

The issue was a CSS issue.

Inspecting the A element in dev tools resulted in the dev tools focusing on the HTML element, not the A element.

Looking at the CSS rules for a div element that was an ancestor of the A tag, I noticed a z-index of -2 and vaguely recalled z-index influencing the clickability of its descendant tags.

I was able to set The z-index to 0, then add a positive z-index to a different element entirely, and regained the functionality of the link.